# SwiftData: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Tags: swift-data

When using `SwiftData` and defining a `@Model`, there may be an error `Missing argument for parameter #1 in call` that is rather strange.

It is caused by a property initialization that does not mention the type, e.g.:
`public var dateSpec: DateSpec = .init()`

It can be fixed by adding the type explicitly:
`public var dateSpec: DateSpec = DateSpec.init()`

I hope this helps anyone struggling with the same effect. It's rather hard to find this out, as the error message is rather unspecific.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer rather than as a part of the question.